# Move row from csv file into existing xml file

Tags: xml, csv, import, export

i'm looking for a solution to solve my problem.

I have two files, one csv file ( products weights ) and one xml file ( products - with all details ).

I need to move one column from csv file to xml file, xml file looks like:

```
<node>
        <ItemNumber>10448WR</ItemNumber>
        <EAN>4014803005885</EAN>
        <Name1>equiSTOP B</Name1>
        <Name2>equistop B, 6 Volt</Name2>
        <BaaNName>equistop B, 6 Volt</BaaNName>
        <DescriptionShort></DescriptionShort>
    <DescriptionLong>

    </DescriptionLong>
    <Category1>Electric fencing &gt; horizont energiser &gt; </Category1>
    <Price>84.5</Price>
    <Picture_URL></Picture_URL>
</node>
```

inside the node i need to insert the value of each row from weights column.

How can i do that?

Comment: Do you want to know the tools to use to read CSV file and write to a XML file?

Comment: I think that will be useful. But the point is, i want something to do that automaticaly, because there are about 3000 products. Doesn't mean  if i have to buy it or it's free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCSV(http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read the CSV file and dom4j(http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html) to modify the XML.

Comment: Any solution using php?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have experience in php.